# Hide an element after clicking on it

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, hide

**Todo :**

- Hide an element smoothly after clicking on it , like in this page https://www.alphafx.co.uk/  , when you click on the letter A it fades away smoothly
- Achieve this effect with just HTML,CSS,JavaScript ?

```js
    var foo = document.getElementById('foo');

document.getElementById('hide-button').onclick = function () {
    foo.className = 'hidden';
};

document.getElementById('show-button').onclick = function () {
    foo.className = '';
};
```

```css
       #foo {
    transition-property: visibility, opacity;
    transition-duration: 0s, 1s;
}

#foo.hidden {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition-property: opacity, visibility;
    transition-duration: 1s, 0s;
    transition-delay: 0s, 1s;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" id="foo">Text</a>
<button id="hide-button">Hide</button>
<button id="show-button">Show</button>
```

Comment: `I've tried a lot` Can you please include your effort in your question? Downvoters are coming...

Comment: Include what you have tried

Comment: The most easiest way is to use animate(from jquery) and opacity.

Comment: Please show your efforts through code

Comment: I am sorry I am new to stackoverflow.com , I will add code later

Comment: I have added the code .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using jQuery `fadeOut` check working fidle below:

Using jQuery

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>fadeOut demo</title>
  <style>
    .hide {
      font-size: 150%;
      cursor: pointer;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    h1 {
      text-align: center;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="hide">
    <h1>A</h1>
    <p>
      If you click on this paragraph you'll see it just fade away.
    </p>
  </div>
  <script>
    $(".hide").click(function() {
      $(".hide").fadeOut("slow");
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Using JavaScript

```js
function fadeOutEffect() {
  var fadeTarget = document.getElementById("hide");
  var fadeEffect = setInterval(function() {
    if (!fadeTarget.style.opacity) {
      fadeTarget.style.opacity = 1;
    }
    if (fadeTarget.style.opacity > 0) {
      fadeTarget.style.opacity -= 0.1;
    } else {
      clearInterval(fadeEffect);
    }
  }, 200);
}

document.getElementById("hide").addEventListener('click', fadeOutEffect);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>fadeOut demo</title>
  <style>
    #hide {
      font-size: 150%;
      cursor: pointer;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    h1 {
      text-align: center;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="hide">
    <h1>A</h1>
    <p>
      If you click on this paragraph you'll see it just fade away.
    </p>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the fast answer , but is it possible with just CSS and Javascript ?

Comment: Yes @AliceEvans it is possible check updated snippet using javascript

Comment: Thank you very much . You are amazing! That's what I needed !

Answer (score 0):

**Please try this:**

```js
$(function() {
    $('#spantext').on('click', function() {
      // $(this).hide();

      $(this).fadeOut("slow"); // if you want to hide it slow
        
    });

    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="spantext">this is a text</span>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the fast answer , but is it possible to let it fade away more smoothly?

Comment: try this: $(this).fadeOut("slow");

Comment: Welcome. Please mark as answer if it fulfill your desire.

Comment: I am really sorry .I upvoted your answer but I didn't mark it as an answer because someone provided it earlier and unfortunately I can't check more answers .

Answer (score 0):

What you want is just an animation to hide the view.

You can use `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` for getting such beautiful effects. You can see the sample code below.

```html
   <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#btn1").click(function(){
                $("#box").animate({opacity: 0});
            });
            $("#btn2").click(function(){
                $("#box").animate({opacity: 1});
            });
        });
    </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="btn1">Animate</button>
        <button id="btn2">Reset</button>
        <div id="box" style="background:#98bf21;height:100px;width:100px;margin:6px;"></div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this using jQuery fadeOut() effect.
Below is the w3scool reference:

```
https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_fadeout.asp
```

Click on "try it yourself>" button and you can modify the code as per your requirement.

Here is another working example for you:

```
https://jsfiddle.net/kag4jqyh/
```

Comment: As `.fadeOut()` is already mentioned in other answer, so instead of making it your new answer, you should have upvoted that answer.

Comment: I've tried upvoting your answers , but it doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: As you are a new user your up vote won't be reflected. Try to select it as a "Right answer".  Have you got your answer or not?

Comment: @AbhishekKumar  Okay, Thank you for the suggestion. Actually I referenced him the direct link where he can edit the code by himself, Am I right ? And anyway *I'll keep it in mind.*

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer in vanilla JavaScript (without using jQuery)

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" id="foo" class="foo">Text</a>
<br />
<button id="hide-button" onclick="hideButton()">Hide</button>
<button id="show-button" onclick="showButton()">Show</button>
```

**JavaScript**

```
const hideButton = () => {
    document.getElementById("foo").classList.add('hidden');
}

const showButton = () => {
    document.getElementById("foo").classList.remove('hidden');
}
```

**CSS**

```
 .foo {
  transition-property: visibility, opacity;
  transition-duration: 0s, 1s;
}

.foo.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
   visibility: hidden;
   transition-property: opacity, visibility;
   transition-duration: 1s, 0s;
   transition-delay: 0s, 1s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use **JavaScript** rather than using jQuery. then
**Try this**

```js
/******define time-delay only in s(seconds)****/
    var timeSlot = '.3s';
     function hide(obj){
        obj.style.visibility= 'hidden';
        obj.style.opacity= 0.8;
        obj.style.transition= 'visibility 0s linear'+timeSlot+', opacity '+timeSlot+' linear';
    }
```

```css
.div1 {
          font-size: 1.2rem;
          cursor: pointer;
          text-align: center;
          margin-top:-100px;
       }
.logo {
         font-size: 10rem;
      }
```

```html
<div class="div1" onclick="hide(this);">
    <h1 class="logo">A</h1>                 
 </div>
```

Comment: you can also use 'margin-top' to remove space create by visibility